# Characterizations Id (diode current) - Vd (diode voltage) IN4728A

Tags: diodes

[image]

I´m graphing the diode voltage and the diode current. This graph would have to give a no linear graph.

[image]

My graph is giving this curve:

[image]

What is my error?

Comment: 1N4728 is a 3.3V Zener  > How did you test this? This part is 10 Ohms at 76mA @ 3.3V (reverse bias)

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist , I made the measure using the oscilloscope to verificate the values of the diode voltage and the resistor voltage. I variete the voltage source with some values between 0 and 2,5 volts

Comment: If you sweep it +/-5V sine, 50 Ohms  and measure the diode voltage and current (using 1 Ohm to gnd), you will get Figure 1, the correct result. using chan 1 vs Ch 2

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist It's dc simple source

Comment: You need to do as I said  or sweep DC 0 to 5V then reverse and repeat  and measure across diode NOT the resistor, You just plotted the resistor

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist But, Is the same with a DC source. isn't it?

Comment: No you are measuring the wrong voltage or  current

Comment: What’s the y-axis scale? What do you expect to see below the Zener knee?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feq1uz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Simulation here http://tinyurl.com/y8ex9l2l